# Por qué no funciona el margin en header?

Tags: html, css

Estoy aprendiendo html y css, y me encuentro con un problema. Tengo un header con imagen dentro del body, y al ponerle margin 0, no le quita el espacio. Más que una solución quisiera una explicación de porqué pasa esto. Gracias

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Compañía</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css"> </head>

<body>
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Purchase</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
</body>

</html>
```

---

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    background: url(verde.jpg);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 420px;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no le quita el espacio de arriba? te refieres a ese espacio? no entiendo del todo

Comment: Si, al que está arriba(encima del "about").

Comment: Es una decisión de facto usar un css reset. Te recomiendo [Normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

Answer (score 3):

El problema en realidad es el tag `ul` el cual tambien es un componente que tiene margin, padding, border y content, entonces el espacio que ves arriba es el espacio generado por el tag `ul`.

> conclusión: poner `margin:0` a `ul`

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    background: url(http://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/articles/2916/large/five-universal-personality-traits-of-the-golden-retriever-556d979a5dbc8.jpg);
    padding: 0;
    height: 420px;
}

ul{
margin:0;
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Purchase</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
</body>
```

Comment: Gracias, si funciona. Pero este comportamiento es normal ? Me parece poco lógico ya que el "ul" está más adentro que el "header" , por lo tanto el header debería limitarlo. Tienes algunas referencias o algo que me recomiendes leer ?.

Comment: @eag845 no soy experto en css, pero creo que hay algunos bugs aun no resueltos por los navegadores y que nosotros lo sufrimos.

Comment: Es un comportamiento estándar. Por defecto, el navegador asigna reglas a cada etiqueta. Es por eso que algunas cosas se ven diferentes en uno y otro navegador. Por esta razón te puse el comentario que, en el desarrollo frontend, es una decisión "de facto" usar un css reset como es [Normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).